# Discord.js: How do you add roles with a bot in the new 12.0.0 update?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a `softmute` command and I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`

```js
const muteduser = message.mentions.users.first();
const muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == 'Muted')
if (message.guild.member(muteduser).bannable) {
  const ismember = message.guild.member(muteduser)
  muteduser.roles.add(muterole.id);
```

Comment: Could you show the rest of your code? how did you define `muteduser`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0DL2Lgm6 Here's a pastebin containing that portion of the code. Hope it helps! (ps. it's in another language. that isn't important though.)

Comment: It'd be better if you edit your code into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue stems from the fact that you defined `muteduser` as a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) not a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

You need to replace `const muteduser = message.mentions.users.first();` with `const muteduser = message.mentions.members.first();`